# How to find the most frequent appearence in one column for different values in a different column of a grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

The question is not so clear I guess, so here is an example:
given a dataframe:

| company_name | company_size | company_acitivity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 eleven | 5 | restaurant |
| 7 eleven | 5 | supermarket |
| 7 eleven | 10 | supermarket |
| goldman sachs | 100 | bank |
| goldman sachs | 200 | restaurant |
| goldman sachs | 200 | bank |

I want to group the dataframe by company name and then replace the values in the organization_size and organization_acitivity columns with the values that have the highest occurrence for the respective company and column.

So in the end the dataframe should look like this:

| company_name | company_size | company_acitivity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 eleven | 5 | supermarket |
| goldman sachs | 200 | bank |

I tried this:

```
df.groupby("organization_name",group_keys=True)["organization_activity"].apply(lambda x: x.mode())
```

But it only gives me

> "AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mode'".

Does someone have an idea for an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to select a column after the groupby, since you want to apply that to all the available columns.

Try this:

```
df.groupby('company_name').apply(lambda x: x.mode()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    company_name  company_size company_acitivity
0       7 eleven             5       supermarket
1  goldman sachs           200              bank
```